# How to filter from a default value in mongoose array with nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

This is my model and I want to filter data from status: "await". Here I attached my controller. What's wrong?

```
status: {
      type: Array,
      Array: ["accepted",
      "unrepairable",
      "completed",
      "handedOver",
      "await",
      "started",],
      default: "started",
    },
```

this is my controller.

```
exports.findawaitrepairs = (req, res) => {
  Repair.find({status:"await"})
    .then((data) => {
      res.send(data);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      res.status(500).send({
        message: err.message || "Some error occurred while retrieving repair.",
      });
    });
};
```

When I filter this with postman, it just gives an empty array.

Comment: Have you checked whether there is any document in the DB with status as  'await'

Comment: Side note: You define as type an array but the default is a string.

Comment: Thank you I changed it. but the same error occurred. This is my code snippt               exports.findAwaitRepairs = (req, res) => {
  Repair.find({status:AWAIT})
    .then((data) => {
      res.send(data);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      res.status(500).send({
        message: err.message || "Some error occurred while retrieving repair.",
      });
    });
};